# Trying to implement a Python Decorator, stuck in a few places

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am currently learning about decorators, this example is supposed to be a basic decorator that saves the result of a recursive fibonacci function, but there are several questions I have.  first of all "fn", is that just the name of a variable? or is it a part of the python language.  Same question for 'KeyError'.  I also don't understand why in the body of the function, args sometimes has a * in front and other times doesn't (shouldn't it always have a *)

```
def memoize(fn):
    stored_results = {}

    def memoized(*args):
        try:
            return stored_results[args]
        except KeyError:
            result = stored_results[args]=fn(*args)
            return result
return memoized

def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2))


@memoize
fibonacci(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Indent correctly.

   ```
   def memoize(fn):
       stored_results = {}

       def memoized(*args):
           try:
               return stored_results[args]
           except KeyError:
               result = stored_results[args]=fn(*args)
               return result
       return memoized
   #^^^
   ```
2. `@memoize` should be before the `def ...` line.

   ```
   @memoize # <-- should be here
   def fibonacci(n):
       if n == 0 or n == 1:
           return n
       else:
           return (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2))
   ```
3. Just call `fibonacci` without `@memoize`

   ```
   fibonacci(5)
   ```

---

> first of all "fn", is that just the name of a variable?

A function object. Here, it is the `fibonacci` function.

> Same question for 'KeyError'

If there's no previously memoized value for the argument, `stored_results[args]` raises `KeyError`. (`TypeError` if you pass unhashable value as argument).

> I also don't understand why in the body of the function, args sometimes has a * in front

To make `memoize` decorator to work with another function which could take multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks! And I understand that args means multiple arguments, but I still don't understand why sometimes in this example, there is a star in front and sometimes there isn't

Comment: @user2897013, It depend on the use case of the decorator. If the decorator is supposed to be used arbitrary functions (argument could vary), it use `*`, if it is supposed to be used by functions that has fixed arguments, it specify that arguments.